# Trouble extracting selected contrast pairs from either pairwise Summary() or Confint()

Tags: r, emmeans, pairwise

There are 190 pairwise contrasts that appear in a summary() or confint(). If I use summary() or confint() I can manually located the selected contrast in the console. Instead, I would like to find code to extract the selected contrast.

This is the code I have tried:

```
mN3em = emmeans(mN3, specs = 'region') # calculate estimated region means
mN3tuk = contrast(mN3em, method = 'pairwise') # perform tukey's for pairwise mult. comparisons
summary(mN3tuk)
summary(mN3tuk, infer = TRUE)$contrasts$"853 - 902"

mN3em = emmeans(mN3, specs = 'region') # calculate estimated region means
mN3tuk = contrast(mN3em, method = 'pairwise') # perform tukey's pairwise multiple comparisons
confint(mN3tuk) #check confidence interval
confint(mN3tuk)$estimate['region1573 - region1575']
```

When using the codes to attempt isolation of select pair, they return

```
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want just a few contrasts, but you have created a quagmire by generating all pairwise comparisons. There are other possibilities, for example `contrast(mN3em, "consec")` just compares each mean with the next one. Or instead of `"consec"` or `"pairwise"`, you can give a `list` of the contrast coefficients you want, e.g.,

```
coeflist = list(`m5-m4` = c(0,0,0,-1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                `m8-m1` = c(-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
contrast(mN#em, coeflist)
```